# Evaluating limit $L=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\csc^2x}\right)^{\sin^2x}$

Tags: limits

I came across this limit in a book and I can't quite figure it out...

$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\csc^2x}\right)^{\sin^2x}$$
where $n$ is a natural number....
I tried doing $e^{\ln L}$ and doing L'Hospital but reached nowhere....
I think I should use squeeze theorem but cant figure it out

After plotting the graph and computing values I believe the answer is $n$ ....
Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_j=2\pi j+\pi/2$. Then $\sin(x_j)=1$ for all $j$, so the sum is constant on this subsequence and its value is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

On the other hand, take $x_j=2\pi j + \pi/4$. Then $\sin(x_j)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for all $j$, so the sum is constant along this subsequence which tends to infinity, but the constant is different from before:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}\right)^{1/2}$$

so the limit does not exist, unless $n=1$, in which case it is equal to $1$.

Comment: You mean "unless $n=1$", don't you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}
=n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac kn\right)^{\csc^2(x)}=1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}=n
$$
However, since $\sin^2(x)$ and $\csc^2(x)$ have period $\pi$, and when $x=\left(k+\frac12\right)\pi$,
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\csc^2(x)}\right)^{\sin^2(x)}=\frac{n^2+n}2
$$
which, for $n\gt1$, does not equal $n$. Therefore, for $n\gt1$, the limit as $x\to\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: Oh... I am very much sorry.. I mistyped the limit to infinity instead of zero

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\sin^2(x)$. Your limit is the same as:

$$\lim_{y\to0^{+}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\right)^{y}$$ and the trig stuff is just a distraction. You have:

$$\exp\left(\lim_{y\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\right)}{1/y}\right)$$

which, by L'Hospital is:

$$\exp\left(\lim_{y\to0^{+}}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\ln(k)(-1/y^2)\right)}{-1/y^2}\right)$$

which is:

$$\exp\left(\lim_{y\to0^{+}}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\ln(k)\right)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/y}\right)}\right)$$

which is:

$$\exp\left(\lim_{y\to0^{+}}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(k/n)^{1/y}\ln(k)\right)}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n(k/n)^{1/y}\right)}\right)=\exp(\ln(n))=n$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer.... I had also reached the same second last step but couldn't do the final one... Thanks for showing that

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
L & \equiv \lim_{x \to 0}
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{\csc^{2}\pars{x}}}^{\sin^{2}\pars{x}} =
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}}^{1/x}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{n - k}^{x} =
n^{x}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{1 - {k \over n}}^{x}
\\[5mm] & =
n^{x}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\exp\pars{x\ln\pars{1 - {k \over n}}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
n^{x}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-\,{x \over n}\,k}\,\dd k =
{n^{x + 1} \over x}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}}^{1/x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{n^{1 + 1/x} \over x^{1/x}} \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ \infty}
{\LARGE \to}\,\,\,
\bbx{\large n}
\end{align}